# Using JSON file in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have a series of high and low temperatures that I would like to display in a column range chart with Highcharts.

I would specifically like a chart like the one shown in the demo example at: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/columnrange

I have placed my data in a file called datatest.json, and it contains this text:

```
[
[1230771600000, -5.8, 10.1],
[1230858000000, -4.1, 1.4],
[1230944400000, -0.5, 4.1],
[1231030800000, -8.9, -0.7],
[1231117200000, -9.7, -3.7],
[1231203600000, -3.4, 3.2],
[1231290000000, -3.9, -0.2],
[1231376400000, -2.4, 6.7],
[1231462800000, 3.8, 6.9],
[1262221200000, -12.2, -6.5]
]
```

When I load the data from the file, it doesn't give me a chart.  For example, with this:

```
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('data/datatest.json', function (data) {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            chart: {
                type: 'columnrange'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 2
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Temperature variation by day'
            },

            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Temperatures',
                data: data
            }]

        });
    });

});
```

But if I put the data directly into my code (as follows), it does display the chart as I expect:

```
$(function () {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            chart: {
                type: 'columnrange'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 2
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Temperature variation by day'
            },

            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Temperatures',
                data: [
[1230771600000, -5.8, 10.1],
[1230858000000, -4.1, 1.4],
[1230944400000, -0.5, 4.1],
[1231030800000, -8.9, -0.7],
[1231117200000, -9.7, -3.7],
[1231203600000, -3.4, 3.2],
[1231290000000, -3.9, -0.2],
[1231376400000, -2.4, 6.7],
[1231462800000, 3.8, 6.9],
[1262221200000, -12.2, -6.5]
]
            }]

        });

});
```

I think that I am either formatting the data incorrectly in my data file, or that I'm not reading from the file in the proper way.

Any suggestions or guidance to help me get on the right track would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the data, can you see it in console?

Comment: Because it is not JSON, it should be object {} not array.

Comment: As @SebastianBochan stated. Your JSON is not in valid JSON format so inputting it as such will not work. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON for example JSON format.

Comment: @SebastianBochan  must still be misunderstanding. I added { and } to the beginning and end of my file, and I'm still not getting anything to display.  To make sure that I can read the file, I verified that $('#dataInfo').load('data/datatest.json'); works to read the file, and I get the text from the file in my browser.  Perhaps there is some other detail about the JSON formatting that I'm missing.

Comment: Have you tried ot validate your JSON if is correct? Please paste yor JSON output here.

Comment: @SebastianBochan. Thank you for your guidance.  You got me going in the right direction with the suggestion to validate the JSON.  I found a website to validate the JSON that I was using.  I needed to start it with {"data": and then the array of arrays.  It also meant that I needed to reference the array of arrays for what I wanted with data.data.  I'm new to stackoverflow, and so I'm not positive about how to post the answer to this question.  But I'll give it a shot and try to include details about where I was going wrong, and what I did to fix things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @SebastianBochan for directing my attention to the fact that my JSON was not valid.

Here is an abbreviated clip of what the correctly formatted JSON looks like:

```
{
"data":
[
[1420640460000,36.7,37.25],
[1420640520000,37.19,37.74],
[1420640580000,37.74,38.6],
[1420640640000,38.72,39.33],
[1420640700000,39.33,39.51]
]
}
```

I used a JSON validator: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

It didn't matter whether I called it "data" or "temperature"  It just had to be a string, and then when I referenced it, I needed to be sure to reference it as data.data.  If I had called it "temperature" then it would have been data.temperature.  In any case, here is the bit of code:

```
    series: [{
        data: data.data
    }]
```